# SOCKET ERROR: [Errno 111] Connection refused on Ubuntu

Tags: python, sockets, smtp, smtplib

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 311, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 286, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Q: I am getting this error on my ubuntu machine. Question is why so?
The reason being when I execute the same code on Mac OS X 10.7 I don't see this error. And I did not do any special configuration on Mac for this to work.

Comment: Do you have an smtp server installed on your local ubuntu machine?

Comment: @AnandSKumar How do I check that I have one ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your system is running smtp server:

```
netstat -nlt | grep '\<25\>'
```

If your system is running the smtp server, the above command will show somehting like this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: I don't have an smtp server running. How do I start one ?

Comment: @abc, For test purpose you can use `smtpd.py`: `python -m smtpd` ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html )

Comment: Sure I will try that for test. Otherwise what is a permanent solution. If I reboot the Ubuntu box I want the server to come up as well. Which server should I install for that ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are very knowledgable.