# Django : PasswordResetForm Connection refused

Tags: python, django, django-email

I used PasswordResetForm (code source by Django), but I have this error :

```
[Errno 111] Connection refused
...
/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py in create_connection, line 571
...
```

My form PasswordResetForm : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/#PasswordResetForm

My view, idem ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/views/#password_reset ).

My urls :

```
url(r'^parameters/password_reset','password_reset',name="password_reset"),
url(r'^parameters/password_reset_done','password_reset_done',name="password_reset_done"),
url(r'^parameters/password_reset_confirm','password_reset_confirm',name="password_reset_confirm"),
url(r'^parameters/password_reset_complete','password_reset_complete',name="password_reset_complete"),
```

and my settings :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

#AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('backend.EmailAuthBackend',) Authentification : email+password

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'the_website',
    'bootstrapform',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   )

   ROOT_URLCONF = 'the_website.urls'

   WSGI_APPLICATION = 'the_website.wsgi.application'


# Database

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-FR'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


   # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

LOGIN_URL = '/the_website/'
```

When I test in the shell :

```
In [6]: send_mail("Test","Test","xxxx@yahoo.fr", ["yyyy@yahoo.fr"])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-6-0682cb627fb0> in <module>()
 ----> 1 send_mail("Test","Test","xxxx@yahoo.fr",["yyyy@yahoo.fr"])

 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.pyc in send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently, auth_user, auth_password, connection, html_message)
 60         mail.attach_alternative(html_message, 'text/html')
 61 
---> 62     return mail.send()
     63 
     64 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.pyc in send(self, fail_silently)
281             # send to.
282             return 0
--> 283         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
284 
285     def attach(self, filename=None, content=None, mimetype=None):

     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.pyc in send_messages(self, email_messages)
 90             return
 91         with self._lock:
 ---> 92             new_conn_created = self.open()
 93             if not self.connection:
 94                 # We failed silently on open().

 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.pyc in open(self)
 48             connection_params['timeout'] = self.timeout
 49         try:
 ---> 50             self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
 51 
 52             # TLS/SSL are mutually exclusive, so only attempt TLS over

 /usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.pyc in __init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
254         self.esmtp_features = {}
255         if host:
--> 256             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
257             if code != 220:
258                 raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)

/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.pyc in connect(self, host, port)
314         if self.debuglevel > 0:
315             print>>stderr, 'connect:', (host, port)
--> 316         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
317         (code, msg) = self.getreply()
318         if self.debuglevel > 0:

/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.pyc in _get_socket(self, host, port, timeout)
289         if self.debuglevel > 0:
290             print>>stderr, 'connect:', (host, port)
--> 291         return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
292 
293     def connect(self, host='localhost', port=0):

/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
569 
570     if err is not None:
--> 571         raise err
572     else:
573         raise error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Check this SO link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716349/socket-error-errno-111-connection-refused-on-ubuntu

Comment: So I check and I don't find problems. I think my settings is not complete but what ?!..

Comment: I edit the post because I show errors when I test in shell

Comment: I think you need to add [email backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#email-backends) in the settings. You can add a [dummy backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#dummy-backend) instead.

Comment: Idem... How start the smtplib ?

Comment: Check the comments in the ans of the linked question posted above. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a while ago, but I think the same problem is still relevant. 
All you need to do is add some email configuration to your settings.py. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_HOST). Add all of the following to settings.py:

```js
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = '<your smtp server>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<your smtp password>'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<your smtp user email address>'
EMAIL_HOST_PORT = <your smtp port>
```

If you haven't set up an email service, you can link your gmail account for free. Mandrill (smtp.mandrillapp.com) and Sendgrid are both good python-friendly resources as well.

I also noticed that your setup is spread across forms.py, views.py, urls.py, and settings.py. A more efficient setup can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/). It automatically configures views.py and urls.py--no need to add anything. Just make sure your forms.py and settings.py are filled out correctly, and you're golden!